# Short references in bibliography

Tags: citations, thesis

I found the following bibliography in a book:

[image]

Is there a website which generates this kind of references automatically, that is short references?

On google scholar there are only long references:

[image]

---

EDIT: I tried to do it with endnote, but there is not the style that I want. I used all Nature styles.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you want to extract the references from the PDF documents or finding the sources of these references?

Comment: Hello @Younes, I'd like to copy (from website; google scholar does not seem to do it) the references in the above (short) format.

Comment: Try this service: http://excite.west.uni-koblenz.de:8081/excite

Comment: Thank you for the link @Younes, but I have only a paper in my bibliography: https://scholar.google.it/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=a+multi-technique+reconfigurable+electrochemical+biosensor&btnG= How can I obtain the short reference to insert in my thesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Endnote, you might want to select the following output styles (I show their examples of their formatting, too).

Note that these are the first 15 relevant styles in the letter 'A'. There are dozens more.

1. ACS Catal

> Morehouse, S. I.; Tung, R. S., *Journal of Paleontology* **1993**, 17 (2), 198-209.

2. Actachimica Slovenica

> S. I. Morehouse and R. S. Tung, *Journal of Paleontology* **1993**, 17, 198-209.

3. Adv Cancer Res

> Morehouse, S. I., and Tung, R. S. (1993). *Journal of Paleontology* **17**, 198-209.

4. Adv in Applied Ceramics

> S. I. Morehouse and R. S. Tung, *Journal of Paleontology*, 1993, **17**(2), 198-209.

5. Adv in Polymer Technology

> Morehouse, S. I.; Tung, R. S. Journal of Paleontology 1993, 17, 198-209.

6. Adv Mfg Polymer Comp Sci

> S. I. Morehouse and R. S. Tung, Journal of Paleontology, 1993, 17(2), 198-209.

7. Adv Molecular Physiology

> Morehouse, S. I. and Tung, R. S. (1993). *Journal of Paleontology* **17**, 198-209.

8. Adv Organometallic Chem

> S. I. Morehouse and R. S. Tung, *Journal of Paleontology* **17**, 198 (1993).

9. Adv Sci Eng Med

> S. I. Morehouse, and R. S. Tung, *Journal of Paleontology*. 17, 198-209 (1993)

10. Adv Sci Letters

> S. I. Morehouse and R. S. Tung. Journal of Paleontology 17, 2 **(1993)**

11. Advanced Device Materials

> S. I. Morehouse and R. S. Tung, *Journal of Paleontology*, 1993, **17**(2), 198-209.

12. Advanced Functional Materials

> S. I. Morehouse, R. S. Tung, Journal of Paleontology **1993**, 17, 198;

13. Advanced Materials

> S. I. Morehouse, R. S. Tung, Journal of Paleontology 1993, 17, 198;

14. Agri Forest Entomology

> Morehouse, S. I. and Tung, R. S. (1993) *Journal of Paleontology*, **17**, 198-209.

15. AIP Style Manual

> S. I. Morehouse and R. S. Tung, Journal of Paleontology **17** (2), 198-209 (1993).

Comment: Hello St.Inkbug this is exactly what I want. Perfect reply.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, no one copy & paste citations they way you try doing. There are programs like Endnote or Mendeley that are used for citation formatting. Each journal has its own citation formatting, so you do not want to reformat citations by hand each time.

So, after installing the program,  you first import the citations using for example google scholar (see below). Then, in program (at least in Endnote) you choose a style and it will format you citations in Word file accordingly. In case there is no corresponding style, you can edit the existing one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello @student, can you post a figure with the above (my fig. 1) formatting in EndNote please? I would know if EndNote is able to do it.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi it seems that you should try Endnote to find out if it can match your specific needs.

Comment: I added the image. Not sure that this is exactly the formatting you, but these things are pretty flexible in Endnote. I think there is a trial version that you can download.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi - the format you provide is a very common one for technical journals. Yes, EndNote can do it.

Comment: Excellent @student. What is the name of the output style?

Comment: You can take one of the styles of Nature journals and edit bibliography settings. Probably you can find style that will do that out of the box.

Comment: @student why did you say "probably"? You posted a figure, thus you know what is the right style!

Comment: Example I sent you was using  style I edited myself. BTW, you always can edit the reference by hand. Take one of the Nature styles and delete the titles manually.